# Why does the googledrive library in R identifies more than one file with only one file in the Drive folder?

Tags: r, google-drive-api, tiff, google-earth-engine

I am trying to download a .tif file from my Google Drive folder (which is exported to it via Google Earth Engine), using the *googledrive* library. However, when calling the `map` function, I get the following error:

```
Error: 'file' identifies more than one Drive file.
```

I have already managed to download other .tif files with this code, which worked without any error. Why do I get this error, and how do I resolve it? As you can see in the Drive folder (it's public), the folder contains only one file, so why does 'file' identify more than one Drive file?

**Code:**

```
library(googledrive)
library(purrr)

## Store the URL to the folder 
folder_url <- "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Qdp0GN7_BZoU70OrpbEL-vIBBxBa1_Db"

## Identify this folder on Google Drive
## let googledrive know this is a file ID or URL, as opposed to file name
folder <- drive_get(as_id(folder_url))

## Identify files in the folder
files <- drive_ls(folder, pattern = "*.tif")

# Download all files in folder
map(files$name, overwrite = T, drive_download)
```

Comment: I cannot see in your code a variable called `file`, only `files`

Comment: Are there two files with the same name in that folder? It is possible in Google Drive. In that case, the `files` tibble will have a column called `id` (if I remember correctly), that you can use to uniquely identify files.

Comment: @Brian You are right, there were indeed multiple files with the same name in the folder, as Google Drive allows this. However, deleting these folders didn't solve the problem, because Google Drive seems to cache (?) files leading the `googledrive` library to believe there are indeed multiple files with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Google Drive API's method `Files: list` returns you by default an array

Even if the results contain only one file, or no files at all - it will still be an array.

All you need to do is to retrieve the first (`0`) element of this array. You can verify it by testing with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list).

I expect the correct syntax in `R` to be something like 
`files[0]$name` to retrieve the name of the first (even if it is the only) file.

> Also: You should implement some condition statement to verify that the
>   list of files is not empty before you retrieve the file name.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The solution does not work, unfortunately. When I run `files$name`, it does return a vector of the file names in the Drive folder ("NTL_1705.tif"    "NTL_1705_v3.tif" etc.).

Comment: I am not familiar with R, but you need to retrieve the first element of the array `files`

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive allows for multiple files with the exact same name in the same folder. The `googledrive` library does not accept this and thus will throw an error. However, even after deleting "double" files, the error wasn't solved. It seems that Google Drive also keeps some kind of hidden record/cache of the files, even when there are deleted. Only by deleting the entire folder and recreating it, I was able to solve the error.

Comment: As already mentioned, even if you delete "double files", the drive API still assumes that you could contain several files with the same name and thus, provides you a list of all possible files in an array. You need to access the "0" element of this array to retrieve your first (even if it is the only) file. However, in your question you do not provide the code part that contains 'file' which makes it hard to help you.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do with the files once you download them, but if you want to get around the problem with "double files" and arrays, you can address the files by id instead of name - the id of a file opposed to its name is always unique and is returned as a string rather than an array.

Answer (score 0):

Easier is to use the id of the filename:

```
as_id("filename_id")
```